# Trying to use mySQL to Concatenate field then Insert into another table

Tags: mysql, insert, concatenation

I'm trying to use this query below to get images from the images table (which could return multiple results) then insert that into the products table's field image. So, the images table could have `testsku`, `url1` and `testsku`, `url2` and `testsku`, `url3`. Then I need to update the products table where sku is `testsku` and the image field will be `url1$^$url2$^$url3`. Also note that `test-sku` images should be concatenated with `testsku` images.

```
INSERT INTO `products` (image) (SELECT images.sku, group_concat(images.image separator '$^$') 
FROM `images`,`products` 
GROUP BY images.sku) 
WHERE (images.sku=products.sku 
    OR images.sku=CONCAT(products.style,'-',products.color)) 
    AND products.sku='testsku'
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, or how I should alter this query to update the table. I understand that this defeats the purpose of relational tables, but it is a requirement to have all the URLs concatenated in the image field in the products table.

EDIT:

Using the following statement, I am able to return both 'test-sku' urls and 'testsku' urls into the same one row. However I am still having trouble updating the products table to fin testsku and update the image field with the returned value. Please also note that I will need to remove the 'testsku' clause so this could run for all skus.

SELECT p.sku, group_concat(i.image separator '$^$') 
FROM `images` i,`products` p 
WHERE (i.sku=p.sku OR i.sku=CONCAT(p.style,'-',p.color)) AND p.sku='testsku'
GROUP BY p.sku

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You only specify to update one column, `image` but you are selecting two columns (images.sku and the group concat). This will most likely give you an error. The number of columns to be updated and the number selected have to match.

Answer (score 0):

I can spot three things which came up in my mind after looking at your code.

1.You are trying to Insert into one column in products column but your nested Select Query will return two columns. Which could cause mismatch in no of columns in insert query. I think you might need to remove images.sku from Select's column list.

2.Have you notice that you are taking cross join in Select query. (no join) which cause n x m rows in resultant set.

3.You are using Product table two times, once in insert and second time in Select. It will create ambiguity. Assign them unique aliases.

your query could be something like this after changes..

```
INSERT INTO `products` as p1 (image) values (SELECT group_concat(images.image separator '$^$') 
FROM `images`,`products` as p2 
GROUP BY images.sku) 
WHERE (images.sku=p1.sku 
    OR images.sku=CONCAT(p1.style,'-',p1.color)) 
    AND p1.sku='testsku'
```

I hope it will help you.